# in bash printf format how to use the same value in muliples placeholders

Tags: bash, printf

I want to put the number of lines of a file in two place holders of a printf string

```
"%s lines: %s\n"
 ^          ^
 |here  and |here
```

So I get it with two `wc -l`::

```
$ do_stuff() { 
printf "%s ## lines: %5s\n" \
`cat $1 | wc -l` \
`cat $1 | wc -l`;
} 
$ do_stuff ./lpm/modelisator.py
426 ## lines:   426
$
```

it works!

Is there a way like in python to give only one value to the string ?::

```
In [1]: '{0} line {0}'.format(426)                                                                                                                             
Out[1]: '426 line 426'
```

Comment: `var=$(cat "$1" | wc -l); printf "%s %s" "$var" "$var"` ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Type less or run `cat $1 | wc -l` only once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
printf '%s lines: %s\n' "$(wc -l <"$1")"{,}
```